# Unexpected identifier on JSON Eval function at Object.success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

i got error on the line eval it says this is na error eval('result = ' + data.d);

this is my json format. i want may data to set pagination limit in 5 per page but when i increase the data. its show all. i want to limit the data per 5 data per page there is variable pagesize = 5 but its not working because of the eval() error

```
{
  "d": [
    {"FChaOnline":"0","FChaName":"Testing10"},
    {"FChaOnline":"1","FChaName":"Testing1"},
    {"FChaOnline":"0","FChaName":"Testing28"}
  ]
}
```

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.success (JRGMain.js:191)
    at Object.resolveWith (jquery-1.5.1.js:862)
    at done (jquery-1.5.1.js:6591)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery-1.5.1.js:7382)
```

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: './WebService/GetUserFriendList',
            data: '{"PageNo" : "' + PageNo + '", "PageSize" : "5", "UserID" : "' + UserID + '"}',
            success: function(data) {



                var result, TotalItemCount, list;
                eval('result = ' + data.d);
                TotalItemCount = result.TotalItemCount;
                list = result.List;

                PageCount = Math.ceil(TotalItemCount / 5);

                var html = '';
                if (list.length > 5) {
                    $.each(list, function(index, obj) {

                        if (obj.FChaOnline == '0') {
                            html += '<li class="off">' + obj.FChaName + '<span class="state"><img src="./Images/Icon/off_icon.gif" alt="on"></span></li>';
                        } else {
                            html += '<li class="on">' + obj.FChaName + '<span class="state"><img src="./Images/Icon/on_icon.gif" alt="on"></span></li>';
                        }

                    });
                } else {
                    html = '<li class="nothing">There are no friends registered.</li>';
                }

                $('#relation-list').html(html);

                $('#page-no').text(PageNo);
                $('#total-page').text(PageCount);



            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert(data.status + ' : ' + data.statusText + ' : ' + data.responseText);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Firstly, never, ever, **ever** use `eval()`. Secondly, you don't need it here. Just `result = data.d` will work. If you're trying to use `eval()` because `data` is still a string use `result = JSON.parse(data).d;`. Lastly jQuery 1.5.1 is over 9 years out of date. You need to update it

Comment: And don't "write" your own JSON (`data: '{"PageNo" : "...`) -> `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: but the page size is not working?